# Getting viewpager in another activity and setting viewpager position in that activity

Tags: android

I implemented common navigation drawer for all activities, and I implemented that.But now my problem is I have fragments as well as activities in my Navigation drawer,

**I set**

```
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)
```

for all activities to restrict inflating same activity for twice but now I am unable to do the same for fragments of same Activity. If I add the above flag for fragments main activity other fragments are not getting selected how to solve these.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Add extra information in intent and than populate fragment in oncreate or onnewintent method in activity.

Comment: How do I do that please give some sample code

Comment: you are already setting flag, just add putextra tag in intent. for example - how you pass information from one activity to other using intent, do same here.

Comment: actually this is how my code is

Comment: if (id == R.id.nav_all_tasks) {
            Intent main2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainFragmentsActivity.class);
            main2.putExtra("position", 1);
            startActivity(main2);
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
        if (id == R.id.nav_audit) {
            Intent main3 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainFragmentsActivity.class);
            main3.putExtra("position", 2);
            startActivity(main3);
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }

Comment: yes correct , now in MainFragmentsActivity use position tag to populate paticular framgent.

Comment: I am getting Particular fragment in main activity also.But when I select same fragment which is currently visible to us in navigation drawer that particular fragment again inflating once more, so how to stop that currently visible fragment not to inflate one more time

Comment: 1> find fragment by tag if it is null than load it.

2> remove fragment before adding it.

I will prefered  1 option.

Comment: not understood will you provide code

Comment: if that not possible, how to access viewpager in other activity and how to set viewpager.setCurrentItem(position) in that particular activity .

Comment: 1> Fragment fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAG_FRAGMENT);

If this fragment is null than load new as you are doing.

2> else remove about fragment as below.

Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAG_FRAGMENT);
if(fragment != null)
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit();

now create same fragment again and add it .

 Menu mFragment = new Menu();
            ft.add(mFragment).commit();

Comment: I am not getting above.But how to access viewpager from main activity to other activity